# Why do I get a wrong result when constructing a truth list in Prolog?

Tags: list, prolog

I'm trying to create a predicate which is true if the third list is composed of `T` and `F` values, depending on the fact whether two elements of same index from the first and the second list are equal. A query like `truth_list(['abc','def'],['zui','def'],L).` should give `L=['F','T']`.

Here's my try:

```
truth_list([],[],_).
truth_list([H1|T1],[H2|T2],TL):-
    (H1==H2)->(H3='T');(H3='F'),
    Temp=TL,
    TL=[H3|Temp],
    truth_list(T1,T2,TL).
```

I'd be grateful if someone could offer an explanation why this doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we're all on the same page, when I ran the query I got this result:

```
L = ['F'|L].
```

So the first thing that comes to mind is that you're probably reusing a variable, and indeed, the following clauses look suspect:

```
Temp=TL,
TL=[H3|Temp],
```

Variables in Prolog aren't really "assignables" as in other languages; all you can really do is establish a binding, so the above code is the same as saying this:

```
TL=[H3|TL]
```

Which is why our result looks like it does: L=['F'|L]. I rewrote the body slightly to fix the problem and wound up with this code:

```
truth_list([H1|T1],[H2|T2],[H3|TL]):-
    (H1=H2 -> H3='T' ; H3='F'),
    truth_list(T1,T2,TL).
```

You need to have the parentheses around the whole condition or you'll get strange behavior. From there, I just removed the unnecessary `TL` bindings (they can't work anyway because variables in Prolog are not assignables). It turns out once you fix these problems you'll find another problem, which is that you'll get this:

```
L = ['F', 'T'|_G297].
```

If it's not obvious, this is because your base case is too vague and should instead look like this:

```
truth_list([], [], []).
```

So the final corrected version looks like this:

```
truth_list([],[],[]).
truth_list([H1|T1],[H2|T2],[H3|TL]):-
    (H1=H2 -> H3='T' ; H3='F'),
    truth_list(T1,T2,TL).
```

This is usually where @false shows up and points out that we have a problem using the predicate with different instantiations, so let's check that now and avoid some fury:

```
?- truth_list(['abc','def'],['zui','def'],['T','F']).
false.
?- truth_list(['abc','def'],['zui','def'],['F','T']).
true.
?- truth_list(['abc','def'],['zui','def'],['F','T','T']).
false.
?- truth_list(['abc','def'],['zui','def','def'],['F','T','T']).
false.
```

These all look alright, so it doesn't look like we're hallucinating lies when all the arguments are instantiated. That's good. Now let's check partial instantiations:

```
?- truth_list([X, 'def'], ['abc', Y], ['T', 'T']).
X = abc,
Y = def.
```

Cool, that worked.

```
?- truth_list([X, 'def'], ['abc', Y], ['F', 'T']).
false.
```

Eh. Well, it looks like Prolog doesn't know to hallucinate some other binding for that `'F'` value. Not sure if that's a problem or not but I don't see an obvious solution. That means the following probably won't work:

```
?- truth_list(X, Y, ['T', 'T']).
X = Y, Y = [_G296, _G302].
```

Surprising, but it actually did work, assigning to both the same list of two unknowns. Cool. I think we're in good shape.

**Edit**: let's incorporate @false's improvement. Then we get the following:

```
truth_list([], [], []).
truth_list([H1|T1], [H2|T2], [H3|TL]) :-
  (H1 = H2, H3 = 'T' ; dif(H1,H2), H3 = 'F'),
  truth_list(T1, T2, TL).
```

Now we get the desired behavior:

```
?- truth_list([X, 'def'], ['abc', Y], ['F', 'T']).
Y = def,
dif(X, abc) ;
```

So Prolog has inferred that Y is 'def', and concluded that X is at least not 'abc', so this is an improvement.

Comment: to hallucinate Prolog it's sufficient replace (==)/2 with (=)/2. Go figure!

Comment: `truth_list(Xs,Ys,[Tr])` is incomplete. Not enough 'hallucination`. You would be in much better shape with `( H1 = H2, H3 = 'T' ; dif(H1,H2), H3 = 'F' )` which is optimizable for `==` and `\=`. Or `when(?=(H1,H2),(H1==H2->H3='T';H3='F'))`. But there are good points to avoid `when` and `freeze`.

Comment: @false thanks once again for finding the bug. I think I learn more from you when I answer someone else's question than I learn on my own!

Comment: @CapelliC I tried it in SWI with == instead of = and didn't see an improvement; is there something I'm missing? And glad I could amuse!

Comment: I hope my (bad) English doesn't caused me to be misunderstood. I liked your prose....

Answer (score 2):

maplist/4 could simplify your code:

```
truth_list(A, B, C) :-
  maplist(truth_, A, B, C).
truth_(A, B, C) :-
  A == B -> C = 'T' ; C = 'F'.
```

You could also consider to enhance your code for (eventual) reuse.

Instead of arbitrary constants 'T','F' you could use *callables* predicates like `true` and `false`, or `1`, `0` to get expressions directly usable with CLP(FD)